# Update value in an array of object every time a button is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button, and an array of object like so,

```
<button (click)="appendDataToLink()">

test = [
   { name: 'karthik', id: 1, link: '/abc/def/ghi' },
   { name: 'shahbaz', id: 2, link: '/jkl/mno/pqr'}
]
```

when the button is clicked, I want to add a random text in the link of the test array.
like, `link: "/abc/def/ghi/rd-5"`

but whats happening is `link: "/abc/def/ghi/rd-5/rd-7"`
as you can see here rd-7 is appended to it instead of `link: "/abc/def/ghi/rd-7"`

Here is the method appendDataToLink() is called every time the button is clicked.

```
generateRandomNumber() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
appendDataToLink() {
  this.test.forEach( e => {
     e.link = `${e.link}/rd-${this.generateRandomNumber()}`
  });
  console.log(this.test);
}
```

Please find my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vstbmm?file=src/app/app.component.ts) on stackblitz

Comment: Your code example is working just fine. Maybe you're just clicking the button twice

Comment: Every time I click, I have to append the new id

Comment: Your code is working fine

Comment: No, every time, you click only the recent number should be appended. It should replace the old value.

Comment: And exactly that is happening... on every click you add a /rd-x to your uri

Comment: but I want a way to replace the old one with the current one.

Comment: Oh, so you want that last part of the link to change, not to add a new, everytime you click. You could just save the original link and use it for generating the new link [Is this what you want?](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bq8ez?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: well, ok then, you didnt mention replacing, just appendind

Comment: If you read the question completely you can understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Like I linked in my comment, this is a simple way to do it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bq8ez?file=src/app/app.component.ts
You save the original link and use it to generate future links

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments (added solution explanation)

Changing the `appendDataToLink` function to the following:

```js
  appendDataToLink() {
    // immutability - map the old array to a new array instead of mutating old values
    this.test = this.test.map( e => {
      // get the original link property or the current link if it's not set
      var originalLink = e.hasOwnProperty('originalLink') ? e["originalLink"] : e.link;
      // create new object:
      return {
        ...e, // old object destructured
        originalLink: originalLink, // set original link 
        link: `${originalLink}/rd-${this.generateRandomNumber()}` // create a new link based on the original link
      }
    });
    console.log(this.test);
  }
```

This uses the link provided as a basis for generating new links and does not require to modify the original object

Comment: Nice clean solution. Doesn't require the original array to be modified

Comment: You should explain your solution in the answer text while providing the link as a reference. This will help future readers and keep your answer valid should the link become stale.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to maintain a boolean

```
firstTime: boolean = true;
```

then modify append function like

```
appendDataToLink() {
  this.test.forEach((e, i) => {
     if (this.firstTime) {
        if ((this.test.length - 1) === i) { this.firstTime = false; }
        e.link = `${e.link}/rd-${this.generateRandomNumber()}`;
     }
     else {
        e.link = e.link.replace(/.$/, this.generateRandomNumber().toString());
     }
  });
  console.log(this.test);
}
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode a new prop manually. if you can programmatically add a prop it's fine.

Comment: @anonymous check it again please

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to do.
Every time you click the button it will append the random number `'/rd-(randNum)'` onto the existing string.
So if you start with `'/abc/def/ghi'` and click the button it will add onto the string.
Eg:

```
*ButtonClick*: '/abc/def/ghi' -> '/abc/def/ghi/rd-3'
*ButtonClick*: '/abc/def/ghi/rd-3' -> '/abc/def/ghi/rd-3/rd-7'
*ButtonClick*: '/abc/def/ghird-3/rd-7' -> '/abc/def/ghi/rd-3/rd-7/rd-5'
```

etc.

If you want to replace the number at the end of the link with a different number you will need to first remove the last number by using substring before adding the new number.
Also you can add a new field to know if the link has already been altered or if it is the first time the button has been clicked so you don't lose the '/ghi' part:

```
appendDataToLink() {
  this.test.forEach( e => {
     if (e.linkAltered === true) {
         e.link = e.link.substring(0, e.link.lastIndexOf("/"));
     }
     e.link = ${e.link}/rd-${this.generateRandomNumber()};
     e.linkAltered = true;
  });
  console.log(this.test);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Edited stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxy7jh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Take substring from link instead of the link

```
  const link = e.link.substring(0,12);
  e.link = `${link}/rd-${this.generateRandomNumber()}`
```

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a "hack"

Comment: can also use split('/rd') function and take first part and append random number

Answer (score 0):

check this code.

First check weather any string ('rd-') present or not, if it is there replace it or if it is not then simply add it.

```
this.test.forEach( e => {
      if (/rd-[0-9]/.test(e.link)) {
        e.link = (e.link).replace(/rd-[0-9]/, `rd-${this.generateRandomNumber()}`);
      }
      else {
        e.link = `${e.link}/rd-${this.generateRandomNumber()}`
      }
    });
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.